# Action to redirect users to URL

Tags: django, django-admin

Could you tell me how to create an action in the admin site that will redirect users to a certain URL? That is, in the admin site a user chooses this action and finds themselves on Google.

```
def google(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    """
    I myself write some code here to prevent Django from asking users to select an object.
    """

    URL = "https://google.com"

    ... Here goes the code to redirect the user to URL ...

@admin.register(SemanticsCorePhrases)
class SemanticsCorePhrasesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = [google, ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect a user to a URL in the Django admin site, you can use the redirect function from django.shortcuts.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def google(modeladmin, request, queryset):

"""I myself write some code here to prevent Django from asking users to select an object.
"""

    URL = "https://google.com"

    return redirect(URL)

@admin.register(SemanticsCorePhrases)
class SemanticsCorePhrasesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = [google, ]
```

Please see [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#:~:text=xhtml%2Bxml%27](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#:%7E:text=xhtml%2Bxml%27))-,redirect,-()%C2%B6